# what should my variable X be when writing a recursive algorithm

Tags: python, string, for-loop, recursion, selection

I am writing a python program that would output each letter in a string, from the beginning, one at a time and the string is passed as a parameter, but variable X is the main problem in my code. What should I assign it to?

```
def letters(l):
    letterCount=len(l)
    x=letterCount
    if x>-1 and x<(letterCount+1):
        x=letterCount-(letterCount)
        return l[x]
    else:
        print('The session is over!')

p=input('Enter a word: ')
count=len(p)
for i in range(0,count):
    print(letters(p))
```

Comment: Start from 0, and increment it by one at each iteration. Note there's no recursion in your code.

Comment: If you just want to print each letter in a string your `def letters` seems redundant. You can print directly in the loop. Or there is anything else in the code?

Comment: If you are using recursion then there is no need to call the function again by using for loop.

Comment: there wasn't anything else in the code... The errors I got just made me to alter some of the codes which led me to that code I wrote. Thank everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion implies a function that calls itself (with different argument values) while some condition is true. 
Here's a way to achieve your goal:

> ```
> >>> def print_letters(s):
> ...     if not s:  # The string is empty (nothing to print)
> ...         print("The session is over!")
> ...         return
> ...     print(s[0])  # Print the 1st char
> ...     print_letters(s[1:])  # Call itself with the string lacking the 1st char (that was already printed)
> ...
> >>>
> >>> print_letters("abcd")
> a
> b
> c
> d
> The session is over!
> ```

Although recursion can be very handy sometimes (and code looks nice), prefer the iterative approach when possible, as it's simpler (and faster).